# Create numpy array from python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a python list

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to create an array like

```
y_pred = array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

so that i can compare it using

```
print accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

I tried to do it using

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_pred = array('B',l)
```

But it is showing

> TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: Your question is really unclear, do you want a named array? Like a pandas `Series`? Why not just use pandas which is designed for this?

Comment: Sorry... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to do it using numpy. Yes, i want to create a structured array.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Create a structured array from a list

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `y_test`?  To create structured array you need to provide a list of tuples and a matching dtype.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `dtype` argument when constructing a structured array. See: [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html).

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1,2.,'Hello'), (2,3.,"World")],
          dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'f4'), ('baz', 'S10')])
```

I do not know what you are trying to do, exactly, but maybe this is it:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_pred = np.array(np.array(l),dtype=[('B',np.int32)])

# >>> y_pred
# array([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)],
#       dtype=[('B', '<i4')])
```

Answer (score 0):

First `np.array` takes an object like a list and a `dtype`.

In,

```
 array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

it takes 'B' as the object, but `[1,2,3,...]` does not qualify as a `dtype`.

As simple array from a list would be:

```
In [15]: np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[15]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You say you want a `structured array`.  But to make that you need to specify a compound `dtype`, and the data has to be a matching list of tuples.

```
In [14]: np.array([("B", 2), ("C", 3)], dtype='S5,int')
Out[14]: 
array([(b'B', 2), (b'C', 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

But that structure doesn't match your data, one string and a list of 5 numbers. Do you want an array with 1 row (record) or 5?

If you want to compare `y_pred` with another array, you need to match its dtype and shape.  What is `y_test`?